# What is the specific format Message attributes in AWS api gateway integration with AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, integration, amazon-sqs

Scenario:

I want to have an AWS API gateway route that forwards the HTTP POST call request body to the AWS SQS service.
I successfully did that using the new AWS console interface for API gateway and Amazon Simple Queue Service as the integration target.

Now, **the problem** is I want to send a specific request header value as Message attributes to SQS, but the acceptable format in the console is ambiguous as hell!

I tried whatever found on the documents and threads and books that I could find and even tried some similar notation from other services value format, but nothing worked.

When I tried and set different values for the Message attribute like the following, it starts returning 400 error status code in response to the HTTP request that was working before.

I just want to send a request header along the request body to the SQS so I have essential data that is stored on the request header to process the message.

tried values:

```
 - $request.header.valueX
 - {"somename":"$request.header.valueX"}
 - {"Name":"somename","Value":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"$request.header.valueX"}}
```

none of the above formats are acceptable in AWS Console for Message Attribute (optional) advance setting in API gateway integration for SQS.

I could not find any proper value format for Message Attribute.

Thank you very much

[image: AWS API Gateway console for SQS integration]

**Update:**

I tried a solution that worked for me:

because I have control over clients of the service, I defined a new custom header (sample1) with a value in the following format:

```
{"CUSTOM-ATTRIBUTE-NAME": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": "CUSTOM-ATTRIBUTE-VALUE"}}
```

In the *Message attribute -  optional* in the SQS integration page on API Gateway, I set the value to *$request.header.sample1*

the custom-attribute-name will be the SQS message attribute name and the CUSTOM-ATTRIBUTE-VALUE will be the value.

now when I receive the message from SQS, I have both the complete request message body and my custom header in the message attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now it seems that manually defining such integrations is not possible in HTTP API as indicated in [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/kt14o1/api_gateway_http_api_integration_with_sqs_mapping/) recent reddit post. The post also indicates that this is confirmed by AWS support.

The only way to add the attributes to SQS message through HTTP api is simply to post them along with the message, e.g. using curl:

```
curl -i -X POST https://44444444.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/sqs -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"MessageBody":"ggg","MessageAttributes":{"newattribte":{"StringValue":"safffmple","DataType":"String"}}}'
```

when the `Message attributes - optional` is set to  `$request.body.MessageAttributes`.

The alternative is to change to REST API which is much more future reach and such integration between the API and SQS would be possible.

Comment: thank you, although it does not work for most standard header values, it would work with custom header value in the following format.
{"CUSTOM-ATTRIBUTE-NAME": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": "CUSTOM-ATTRIBUTE-VALUE"}}

and for the Message attributes - optional I did set $request.header.myheader

Comment: @Khatibzadeh Thanks for letting now. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 2):

A year too late... but I just got this syntax to work in the Message Attributes field:

```json
{
  "product":
  {
    "DataType":"String",
    "StringValue":"${request.path.product}"
  }
}
```

[AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d08zC.png)

[Resulting SQS message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5LqG.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages. "[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/153968)" is important on SO. Extract the salient information from the links and add it to your answer so _when_ link rot sets in the answer will still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Laurie mentioned, if you want to pass on a request header as message attribute, use this syntax in the Message attribute field,

```
{
  "your-message-attribute": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "${request.header.your-header-name-in-request}"
  }
}
```